# Impossible to remove \n and \t in python3 string?

Tags: python-3.x

So I been trying to format the taken webpage from CL so I can send it to my email, 
but this is what I come up with every time I try anything to remove the `\n` and `\t`

```
b'\n\n\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\n\n\n\t\n\n\n\t
\n\t\t\t
\n\t
\n\t\t
\n\t\t\t
\n 0 favorites\n
\n\n\t\t
\n\t\t
∨
\n\t\t
∧
\n\t\t
\n \n
\n
\n\t \tCL wenatchee all personals casual encounters\n
\n
\n\t\t
\n\t
\n
\n\n\t\t
\n\t\t\t
\n\t\n\t\t\n\t\n\n\n\nReply to: 59nv6-4031116628@pers.craigslist.org\n
\n\n\n\t
\n\t\n\t\tflag [?] :\n\t\t\n\t\t\tmiscategorized\n\t\t\n\t\t\tprohibited\n\t\t\n\t\t\tspam\n\t\t\n\t\t\tbest of\n\t\n
\n\n\t\t

Posted: 2013-08-28, 8:23AM PDT
\n
\n\n
\n \n Well... - w4m - 22 (Wenatchee)\n
```

I have tried strip, replace and even regex but nothing fazes it, it always comes up in my email unaffected by everything.

Here's the code:

```
try:
    if url.find('http://') == -1:
        url = 'http://wenatchee.craigslist.org' + url
    html = urlopen(url).read()
    html = str(html)
    html = re.sub('\s+',' ', html)
    print(html)
    part2 = MIMEText(html, 'html')
    msg.attach(part2)
    s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
    s.sendmail(me, you, msg.as_string())
    s.quit()
```

Comment: This code doesn't run and your post is practically unformatted. Format your question, and post a [short, self-contained example](http://sscce.org/) that we can copy and paste to reproduce your problem, or else you're unlikely to get any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your issue is that despite all evidence to the contrary, you still have a `bytes` object rather than the `str` that you're hoping for. Thus your attempts come to nothing because without an encoding specified, there's no way to match anything (regexes, replacement parameters, etc) to your `html` string.

What you need to do is [decode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/606199/2069350) the bytes first.

And personally, my favorite method for cleaning up whitespace is to use `string.split` and `string.join`. Here's a working example. I remove all runs of any kind of whitespace, and replace them with single spaces.

```
try:
    html = urlopen('http://wenatchee.craigslist.org').read()
    html = html.decode("utf-8") # Decode the bytes into a useful string
    # Now split the string over all whitespace, then join it together again.
    html = ' '.join(html.split())
    print(html)
    s.quit()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Comment: yes this worked! I didnt know it was still encoded and thats what was tripping me up!

Comment: This answer is so brilliant